# How to use python tornado @gen.coroutine with long running functions

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, tornado

I have a web app that is also doing really intensive data processing.
Some of the functions are extremely slow (think a couple of minutes).

Until now I had an architecture that was spawning new threads/process per connection so those slow functions don't block other users. But this is consuming way too much memory and it is against tornado architecture.

So I am wondering if there is a solution to this kind of issue.
My code look like this:

```
# code that is using to much memory because of the new threads being spawned 
def handler():
   thread = Thread(target = really_slow_function)
   thread.start()
   thread.join()
   return "done"

def really_slow_function():
   # this is an example of an intensive function
   # which should be treated as a blackbox
   sleep(100)
   return "done"
```

After refactoring I have the following code:

```
#code that doesn't scale because all the requests are block on that one slow request.
@gen.coroutine
def handler():
   yield really_slow_function()
   raise gen.Return("done")

def really_slow_function():
   # this is an example of an intensive function
   # which should be treated as a blackbox
   sleep(100)
   return "done"
```

The issue with this refactor is that the tornado server is blocking on the `really_slow_function` and not able to serve the other requests in the meantime.

So the question is: is there a way of refactoring the handler WITHOUT touching the `really_slow_function` and WITHOUT creating new threads/process?

Comment: Blocking functions need to be run in a separate thread. There's no way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (from the `concurrent.futures` package) to run long-running function in separate threads without starting a new thread each time.

```
async def handler():
    await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, really_slow_function)
    return "done"
```

If you want to control exactly how many threads are eligible to run this function, you can make your own executor and pass it instead of `None`.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good!
If I may push the question a little bit further.
Do you know if it is possible to do some kind of routing in the "executor"? So I can re-use the thread that already has some kind of object in memory based on their usage?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really; the point of the Executor interface is that you don't care about particular threads. If you do care about particular threads, you'll probably need to create and manage them on their own.